# When does spring session in Redis gets deleted?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session, spring-boot-3

I am using spring-session with Redis. After upgrading **from springboot 2.7 to 3.1.3**, some of the tests starts to fail. The session planted to Redis as an initial setup was somehow deleted causing some of the sessionAttr missing.

Previously our test setup has following HSET on Redis:

```
HSET "spring:session:sessions:aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee" "sessionAttr:name" "\"andrew\""
HSET "spring:session:sessions:aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee" "sessionAttr:age" "\"23\""
```

After the upgrade, we have to set three additional **mandatory properties** below:

```
HSET "spring:session:sessions:aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee" "maxInactiveInterval" "600"
HSET "spring:session:sessions:aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee" "creationTime" "1696500489000"
HSET "spring:session:sessions:aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee" "lastAccessedTime" "1696500489000"
```

And, the request would have a custom name **MY-SESSION** in the cookie

```
"cookie":"MY-SESSION=aaaa-bbbb-dddd-e3ee"
```

When run in debug mode, the saved session would be deleted and new session is created if the createTime is about 4-5min before current time. However if the Epochmilli of the current time, then the session is considered valid and will be retrieved from Redis correctly.

I don't quite understand this behavior. What is the significance of those new **mandatory properties** and when does spring session removes and recreates new session?

I run a redis docker instance locally for this test.

Application.yaml setting

```
spring:
  session:
    cookie:
      name: MY-SESSION
      path: /
    store-type: redis
    timeout: 15m
```

Thanks in advance

the configuration class current is annotated with @EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession